# If $Q^TQ$ is an orthogonal projection then $QQ^T=I$

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality

Consider an $n\times m$ matrix $Q$. If $Q^TQ$ is an orthogonal projection in $\mathbb{R}^m$ onto a subspace of dimension $n$ then prove that $QQ^T=I$.

Proof: Using, the idempotent property of projection we can write:
$$Q^TQQ^TQ=Q^TQ$$ or  $Q^T(QQ^T-I)Q=0$. How should this imply, $QQ^T-I=0$?

Comment: What are yu trying to prove isn't generally true. You can see that for example for $$ Q =Q^T = \left[\begin{array}{cc}1&0\\0&0\end{array}\right]$$ Perhaps you've missed some assumptions? Or maybe you're supposed to prove it in the opposite direction, if $QQ^T = I$ then $QQ^T$ is an orthogonal projection?

Comment: The question appears in page 81 as Remark 4.1.7 of the following book:
https://www.math.uci.edu/~rvershyn/papers/HDP-book/HDP-book.pdf

Comment: In the book there is indeed an additional assumption: that $Q^TQ$ is orthogonal projection **onto a subspace of dimension $n$**.

Comment: Thanks, let me correct the question.

Answer (score 3):

If
$$\dim {\rm im\,} Q^TQ  = n$$
it means that
$$\dim {\rm im\,} Q\ge n$$
(because multiplying by another operator cannot increase the dimension of the image). But since $Q: \mathbb{R}^m \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$, it just means that
$$ {\rm im\,} Q = \mathbb{R}^n $$
The equation
$$ Q^T(QQ^T -I)Q = 0 $$
can be read as
$$ Q^T(QQ^T -I)|_{{\rm im\,}Q} = 0 $$
but since $ {\rm im\,} Q = \mathbb{R}^n $, it just means that
$$ Q^T(QQ^T -I) = 0 $$
By transposing this equation we have
$$ (QQ^T -I)Q = 0 $$
Using the same argument again, we get
$$ QQ^T - I = 0$$